# How to query Solr for empty field or specific value

Tags: solr

How to do an OR expression that filters to either blank field or a specific value?

This does not seem to do it:

`q=(-PrivacyLevel:*) OR PrivacyLevel:2`

Thanks

Comment: blank or non-existent (i.e: undefined)?

Answer (score 8):

The answer is to use double negation as suggested by [Maurizio In denmark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044661/how-to-filter-search-by-values-that-are-not-available/17045097#17211744). Mathematically this is identical to the non-negated query, however, Solr only understands the double negated version:

```
q=-(-PrivacyLevel:2 PrivacyLevel:*)
```

Note: This also works for filter queries:

```
fq=-(-PrivacyLevel:2 PrivacyLevel:*)
```

Answer (score 6):

Checkout [SolrQuerySyntax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax#Differences_From_Lucene_Query_Parser)

Pure Negative Queries :-

`-field:[* TO *]` finds all documents without a value for field

You can try :-

`q=-PrivacyLevel:[* TO *] OR PrivacyLevel:2`

Comment: you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17044661/how-to-filter-search-by-values-that-are-not-available/17045097#17045097

Comment: A link to the very same answer. How redundant!

Answer (score 3):

This should works:

```
q=(*:* AND -PrivacyLevel:[* TO *]) OR PrivacyLevel:2
```

Answer (score 3):

This is worked for me:

```
fq=(* -type:[ * TO * ]) || (* +type:company)
```

Answer (score 1):

See also [Solr field query (fq) with AND and OR operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33002648/solr-field-query-fq-with-and-and-or-operator/41258717#41258717) for a potential problem and a workaround with negative query.

Answer (score 0):

The solution worked for me is `q = -PrivacyLevel:(*) PrivacyLevel:("2")`.

Happy coding.

Comment: `**`? That is not a valid query term.

Comment: * and ** both does the same job. To avoid ambiguity, I edit my answer.