# how to filter search by values that are not available

Tags: python, django, solr, django-haystack

I have a list of items as:

```
i = SearchQuerySet().models(Item)
```

now, each item in `i` has a attribute, `price`

I want to narrow the result in which price information is **not available** along with the ones falling in a given range

something like

```
i.narrow('price:( None OR [300 TO 400 ] )')
```

how can that be done?

Comment: I wonder if [this syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4238609/how-to-query-solr-for-empty-fields) might work?

Comment: @MartijnPieters that syntax worked separately, but not along with OR. I have updated my  question

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
-(-price:[300 TO 400] AND price:[* TO *])
```

is logically the same and it works in Solr.

Comment: why ~AND` not `OR` though it works for both `AND` and `OR`, i wonder why

Comment: I don't think it work with OR. have a look at this link: http://whatis.techtarget.com/definition/logic-gate-AND-OR-XOR-NOT-NAND-NOR-and-XNOR. 
If you forget for a second the negative inside the parentesys what we are actualy doing here in a NAND between 2 term and that can be quite similar to a OR but not in all cases, be careful.

Answer (score 6):

As per the [SolrQuerySyntax](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax#Differences_From_Lucene_Query_Parser)

Pure Negative Queries:

`-field:[* TO *]` finds all documents without a value for field

You can try:

`q=(*:* -price:[* TO *]) OR price:[300 TO 400]`

Comment: it still is not giving me items with prices between 300 to 400

Comment: whats the field type of prices ? sint ?? or string/text ?

Comment: price field is decimal (float)

Comment: how does your query look now ? can you update your question ?

Comment: i dont understand.  I want price falling in a particular range and the ones with None values. i dont know the query for that

Comment: update the answer with the query. This is tested and works fine.

Comment: can you please give me how to write inside `.narrow`

Comment: Not sure of that. you can paste as is in the narrow without the q= part.

Answer (score 0):

The aim was to sort some items by score based on an boosting by type and plus if a type:bike item has an image.
The result should be:

1. Cars
2. Boats
3. Bikes with an image
4. Bikes without an image

This was my first query approach:
`type:"car"^10000 OR type:"boat"^5000 OR (type:"bike" AND image-type:[* TO *])^100 OR type:"bike"^5` (works fine)

But i forgot old data items without the type field. The should be in the result set like this:

1. Cars
2. Boats
3. Bikes with an image
4. Bikes without an image
5. All items without a type

So i changed my query to `-type:[* TO *] OR type:"car"^10000 OR type:"boat"^5000 OR (type:"bike" AND image-type:[* TO *])^100 OR type:"bike"^5` and ended up with no results.

So i found this thread and tried to change my query to `-(type:[* TO *] OR -type:"car"^10000 OR -type:"boat"^5000 OR -(type:"bike" AND image-type:[* TO *])^100 OR -type:"bike"^5`) like shown in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/17211744/326905

But sadly all items have the same score :(

Answer (score 0):

The double negated query suggested by Maurizio may cause error:

```
unexpected docvalues type NUMERIC for field 'price' (expected one of [SORTED, SORTED_SET]). Re-index with correct docvalues type.
```

(Even after re-indexing. This may have something to do with the `index` and `store` and `docvalues` settings of the field.)

What you could do instead is exempt both ranges (before and after) of the values you are actually interested in:

```
-(price:[* TO 300} price:{400 TO *])
```

Note that values 300 and 400 are excluded by using curly brackets in this negated query and are thus included in the search results.

Answer (score -1):

One can use a `filter query` if you do not care about the document score and want to leverage the filter cache, like:

```
?q=*:*&fq=((-price:[* TO *]) or (price:[300 TO 400]))
```

Comment: Cojucaru, Can you give the query in `models(Item).filter` .. form. I am realyy new to solr and am not able to convert your code into that form

Comment: try something like this models(Item).filter_or(price=None, price__range=[300, 400]) based on https://github.com/soby/django-haystack/commit/71c0b0bdf4e7a25421139901c910a978bb1c5386 for Empty values one needs to use None