# Solr field query (fq) with AND and OR operator

Tags: solr

I have been struggling to form a solr field-query with AND and OR operator. why solr returns different result for 1 and 2, 3 and 4 queries even all queries have same logic-

1. fq=(name:abc AND -city: ( 1 3 )) OR (name:abc AND -loc:(3 K D 5 7))
2. fq=(name:abc AND (-city: ( 1 3 ) OR -loc:(3 K D 5 7)))
3. fq=name:abc&fq=-(city:(1 3) AND loc:(3 K D 5 7))
4. fq=name:abc&fq=(-city:(1 3) OR -loc:(3 K D 5 7))

could anyone please help me understand how solr internally execute above queries?

Comment: See Yonik's answer w.r.t. parsing of "pure negative" queries:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634765/using-or-and-not-in-solr-query/642452#21409106

Comment: Thanks for reply, I was logically thinking from the perspective of Demorgan's law and according to it 3 and 4 both are same-"not (A and B)" is the same as "(not A) or (not B)"

Comment: I've gotten hung up here in the past as well.  Not sure the rationale for the inconsistent behavior.

Comment: Still i have not got answer from the link you suggested. i want to know how  solr internally runs these expression.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This inconsistency is a known issue, and there's an open ticket:  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-3744

This thread covers is in simpler terms:
[Weird Solr/Lucene behaviors with boolean operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363819/weird-solr-lucene-behaviors-with-boolean-operators)

You have some "pure negative" nested queries in your expressions that 
The Lucene query parser expects "negative queries" to be expressed together with a a positive selection query.  In other words *anything but city:foo* is correctly written as `*:* AND -city:foo`.

Try your test with the following changes:

```
 1. <Same>

 2. fq=(name:abc AND (*:* AND -city:(1 3)) OR (*:* AND -loc:(3 K D 5 7)))

 3. <Same> 

 4. fq=name:abc&fq=((*:* AND -city:(1 3)) OR (*:* AND -loc:(3 K D 5 7)))
```

And see if  things tie back up correctly.

Comment: When you pass *debugQuery=true* you want your parsed query to look something like `+name:abc -( +city:(1 3) +loc:(3 K D 5 7) )`  in all cases.

Answer (score 2):

Even `*:* AND -city:foo` does not seem to work reliably for me when I use both `q` and `fq` - e.g., a variant of #4 as below does not work:

```
4b. q=name:abc AND ((*:* AND -city:(1 3)) OR (*:* AND -loc:(3 K D 5 7)))
```

What works for me is to use `id:*` instead of `*:*` when `id` is some required field. Now any variants work.

```
4c. q=name:abc AND ((id:* AND -city:(1 3)) OR (id:* AND -loc:(3 K D 5 7)))
4d. q=name:abc&fq=((id:* AND -city:(1 3)) OR (id:* AND -loc:(3 K D 5 7)))
```